# WPF: ComboBox only refreshes to binding when never opened

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox

I have a combobox and set the itemssource to a list of strings:

```
private List<string> list = new List<string>();
...
ComboBox cbo = new ComboBox();
cbo.ItemsSource = list;
```

The combobox gets filled successful on startup.
But when the list is changed, the combobox doesn't update its items, BUT only when I expanded the items before, else the combobox gets updated...
Also weird: when I trace the count of items of the combobox, the count is the correct updated number, but the displayed items aren't.
Somebody has an idea, what's going on here?

EDIT: See solution in comments to post of Robert

Comment: You should post more of your code.  The problem in the code you posted is solved by using ObservableCollection, but you should add here at least the code that updates your list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need to use ObservableCollection instead of List, because ComboBox needs to be notified whenever the collecion changes.

Comment: I already tried this, but then I get following exception when I want to open the combobox: "An event was unable to invoke any of the subscribers. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040201)"

Comment: What about trying it from xaml via {Binding Items} extension

Comment: Isn't possible in my architecture. But i found out, that the error doesn't appear, when I start the application without debugging (see http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/607403/wpf-crashing-on-cominterop). But I think, this is another problem. So thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Change List into ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 0):

Use ObservalbeCollection. It has inbuilt mechanism to notify and change in the number of items.

Comment: Three times the same answer will make it better... Please first read previous answers!